# Auto refresh a post after duration from a video ends

Tags: jquery, ajax, youtube

Im using this tutroial http://digwp.com/2009/07/display-a-random-post-with-ajax-refresh/# to build a page where my posts with emebeded youtube videos can auto refresh. I also have a function that pulls the duration from the video so what I want to do is use that to make the post section auto refresh when the duration has ended with a 5 second delay. How can I add that to the tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) setInterval() - will allow you to make a call to your refreshing function when the timer has finished, use this to drive your UI changes.